# In Italian is it 10 € or € 10?

Tags: word-usage

In English I always write “the price is $10”. I seem to remember seeing in Italian it is written as 10 € (or 10€?).

Which is right?

Comment: As you can see at this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_and_the_euro#Written_conventions_for_the_euro_in_the_languages_of_EU_member_states) the right one is 10 €.

Comment: Nella pratica, [dipende](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simbolo_dell%27euro).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link. Yes according to the Wikipedia article, most European countries use 10 €.
A few of them (Turkish for example) use €10.

Comment: About 5% of Turkey is a European country... :)